# cancelScheduledValues(x) followed by setValueCurveAtTime(x) throws error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, web-audio-api

I'm using the WebAudio API to crossfade between multiple sources. Fades are queued using [setValueCurveAtTime](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-audioparam-setvaluecurveattime)(curve, time, duration). The WebAudio spec indicates that any subsequent call to setValueCurveAtTime with overlapping durations is not allowed. So I'm calling [cancelScheduledValues](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-audioparam-cancelscheduledvalues)(time) before queuing up new fades. Both Firefox v68 and Chrome v77 throw errors on the second setValueCurveAtTime call however.

The attached snippet contains the minimum amount of code to trigger the errors in either browser. **Click on Start** to trigger the error. Note that it doesn't play any audio as it's not needed for the error to be thrown. The select dropdown allow control of the `time` argument to both functions. In Chrome v77 `time=0` doesn't trigger an error.

Any ideas on how to get this to work in both browsers would be much appreciated!

**Update:** As [Raymond Toy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58206113/1527562) pointed out cancelScheduledValues(t) appears to cancel automations which *started* at `t` or later (not simply active during `t`). By using `cancelScheduledValues(Math.max(t - duration, 0))` the code now appears to work in Chrome. Firefox still fails with a `Operation is not supported` error however.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <button id="start">Start</button>
    <select id="time">
      <option value="0">time=0</option>
      <option value="1">time=currentTime</option>
    </select>
    <pre id="log"></pre>

    <script>
      const select = document.querySelector('#time')
      const log = document.querySelector('#log')
      
      function start() {
        const ctx = new AudioContext()
        ctx.resume()
        const gain = ctx.createGain()
        gain.connect(ctx.destination)

        // Fade in
        gain.gain.setValueCurveAtTime(new Float32Array([0, 1]), 0, 1)

        setTimeout(() => {
          const time = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value === '0' ? 0 : ctx.currentTime

          // Replace fade in with fade out
          // THIS IS THE CALL THAT DOESN'T WORK =====
          // Doesn't work in Firefox nor Chrome:
          // gain.gain.cancelScheduledValues(time)
          // Doesn't work in Firefox:
          gain.gain.cancelScheduledValues(Math.max(time - 1 /* duration of previous fade */, 0))

          try {
            // ERROR IS THROWN HERE =================
            gain.gain.setValueCurveAtTime(new Float32Array([0, 1]), time, 1)
          } catch (error) {
            log.prepend(error.message + '\n')
            throw error
          }
          log.prepend('No error!\n')
        }, 100)
      }

      document.querySelector('#start').addEventListener('click', start)
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I ended up ditching `setValueCurveAtTime()` in favour of multiple `setValueAtTime` calls:

```js
function fade(gainNode, fadeIn, startTime = 0) {
  const duration = 1 // seconds
  const delta = 1 / 100 // number of volume changes per second
  const targetVolume = fadeIn ? 1 : 0
  const currentTime = audioContext.currentTime
  if (!startTime) { startTime = currentTime }

  // We can only read current volume for current startTime, so if queueing a fade
  // we'll have to assume it starts in the other end
  const startingVolume = startTime && startTime !== currentTime
    ? 1 - targetVolume
    : gainNode.gain.value

  // Offset to start at when startingVolume isn't 0 or 1
  let tOffset = equalPowerEasingInverse(startingVolume)
  if (fadeIn) tOffset = 1 - tOffset

  let t = 0 // time iterator [0..1]

  try {
    // Cancel any potentially overlapping fade automations
    gainNode.gain.cancelScheduledValues(Math.max(startTime - duration, 0))

    for (; t + tOffset <= 1; t += delta) {
      // Queue volume change
      gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(
        equalPowerEasing(t + tOffset, fadeIn),
        startTime + t*duration
      )
    }

    // Ensure final value is exact
    gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(targetVolume, startTime + t*duration)
  } catch (error) {
    if (/Failed to execute 'setValueCurveAtTime'|Operation is not supported/.test(error.message)) {
      // Ignore Chrome + Firefox errors
    } else {
      throw error
    }
  }
}

function equalPowerEasing(t, invert = true) {
  if (invert) t = 1 - t
  return Math.cos(t * 0.5 * Math.PI)
}

function equalPowerEasingInverse(x) {
  return Math.acos(x) / 0.5 / Math.PI
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My reading of [cancelScheduledValues](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-audioparam-cancelscheduledvalues) shows that this is working as intended.  The event time for a `setValueCurveAtTime(curve, time, duration)` is `time`.  `cancelScheduledValues(t2)` removes all events whose event time is `t2` or greater.  In your test case, `time` = 0, and `t2` is `currentTime` which is greater than 0.  Thus, nothing is removed from the timeline.  The second call to `setValueCurveAtTime` inserts a new event that does overlap the previous one.  Hence, you get an error.

Having said that, I think this is kind of unexpected.  This could be an error in the WebAudio spec.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I updated the question in response to your answer. I've been unable to find any workarounds for Firefox though.

Comment: The workaround for now is to call cancel with the same time as the first setValueCurveAtTime.  But I also filed https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/2071 to get clarification on this.

Comment: Responded on the github issue. Did you get the cancel to work with Firefox? I was unable to using `cancelScheduledValues(time)` where `time` is the same time as the setValueCurveAtTime call.

Comment: I haven't tried the code on any browser; I was just looking at your code and reading the spec.  But I've also followed up on the issue and you are right, but there are still issues that need to be clarified.